# vba word - force pages count

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a script that browses through document using

```
Set main_browser = Application.Browser
main_browser.Target = wdBrowsePage
main_browser.Next
```

It works as expected only if you press `Ctrl+End` **before the execution** or wait long enough so that Word *counts* the amount of pages in document (it's usually over a thousand pages, so it takes some time)

I am now trying to add "lotsa files" functionality (select a group of files in dialog box and process them all). I discovered the fact that when Word opens a document inside a VBA script, it only processes first couple of pages and moves on.
All I could think of is

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToLast
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
```

and it does not help.

So the question is: how to make Word "wait" while it counts pages or (much better) manually force it to count them?

Comment: I think `Application.ActiveDocument.Repaginate` is what you need. You should call it before you call any of the other code.

Comment: @Seth add it as an answer, I'll accept it, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.ActiveDocument.Repaginate` is what you need. You should call it before you call any of the other code.